# Why is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n] {n^n}=1$ where $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] {n!}=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n] {n^n}=1$ where $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] {n!}=\infty$ ?

We all know that $n^n > n! \ : \forall n$ so how come the factorial "beats" the exponent when it's nth rooted and going to infinity ?

The factorial is behaving as if it's bigger than $n^n$.

Comment: Are you sure about the question [n^n]^(1/n) ?

Comment: Answers are not matching with the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your first limit does not make sense. That is, it doesn't make sense to have the limiting variable outside the limit.

Perhaps you mean
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sqrt[n]{n^n}=1
$$
In that case, then you get, in a similar fashion, for the second limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sqrt[n]{n!}=\frac1e
$$

Comment: Yeah I did it from memory and messed up... It doesn't makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks. If you can please delete this question.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @robjohn Ping the moderators and you will get the following reply: "We are watching what we can to see if there is anything we can see that the script has not. Keep us informed.". But no action will be taken and they will keep watching till the entire site collapses.

Comment: @user17762 "till the entire site collapses." wat

Comment: @user17762: Believe me, we have not done nothing. However, moderators cannot adjust votes. We can only suggest to the community team that something fishy is going on and then they deal with the situation.

Comment: @robjohn Then what are mods for? Just to be silent spectators? For instance, any downvote on MO, pops up a small catchy thing, which says "Please consider adding a comment, if you think this post can be improved" Similarly, cannot the mods get this working here? That would be a start.

Comment: @GinKin Do you understand English?

Comment: @user17762 maybe ?

Comment: @user17762: that would be a job for the developers, and the way to have them work on that would be to make a [meta-tag:feature-request] on meta.

Comment: @robjohn Does anything come out of asking something on meta except for a few answer? Eventually the question will be tagged `status-declined`.

Comment: @user17762: the community team and the developers read appropriately tagged questions on meta. If it is not a good idea or too hard to implement, they will tag a [tag:feature-request] as [tag:status-declined].

Comment: @robjohn Could you point me to one thing, that was raised in the meta and implemented by the community team and the developers?

Comment: @robjohn I have done what you suggested [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/fequre-request-leaving-comment-on-downvoting). Let us see what happens. Also, I do not have anything personally against you. On the contrary, I have high regard for all the mods and other users here.

Comment: @user17762: looking at the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag shows that a good number of items raised on meta have been implemented.

Comment: @Pleasedeleteaccount what happened ? why are you so mad ? not all users are thankless just so you know...

Answer (score 16):

Because $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim \frac{1}{n}(n^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim \frac{n}{n} = 1$

For $(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ take $u_n = n!$. $\lim \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \lim (n+1) = \infty$ that gives $\lim (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \infty$, as $\lim \inf \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \le \lim \inf (u_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \le \lim \sup (u_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \le \lim \sup \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$